# Turtle graphics animation (shelf)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I want to define a function `insert_animate(blockposition, shelf, high)` such that it removes the block at `blockposition` from `shelf` and insert this block into a high position at `high`, where `high` is an integer. The function should find this position between zero and the high position, non-inclusive of high. If no such position is found, the block is inserted at the high position.

I've managed to come up with this function:

```
def insert_animate(blockposition, shelf, high):
    if blockposition==0:
        return shelf
    else:
        a=s.pop(blockposition)
        for i in range(high):
            if a.size<=s[i].size:
                s.insert(i,a)
                break
            else:
                s.insert(high,a)
        return shelf
```

However, this only works on some cases, not all. I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
s = shelf.init_shelf((2, 6, 1, 4, 8, 3, 9))
print(insert_animate(0, s, 0)) # returns [Block size: 2, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
print(insert_animate(3, s, 3)) 
# returns [Block size: 1, Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 4, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
```

**But it should be (for second print):**

```
[Block size: 1, Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 4, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]

print(insert_animate(6, s, 6))
# returns [Block size: 1, Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 4, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 8, Block size: 8, Block size: 8, Block size: 8, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
```

**But it should be:**

```
[Block size: 1, Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
```

Why does my code work for some cases but not for others? Does the issue lie on my for-loop? If anyone could help I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

This is the file that I'm working on:

```
from turtle import *

class Block(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape="square", visible=False)
        self.pu()
        self.shapesize(size * 1.5, 1.5, 2) # square-->rectangle
        self.fillcolor("black")
        self.st()
    def glow(self):
        self.fillcolor("red")
    def unglow(self):
        self.fillcolor("black")
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Block size: {0}".format(self.size)

class Shelf(list):
    def __init__(self, y):
        "create an shelf. y is y-position of first block"
        self.y = y
        self.x = -150
    def push(self, d):
        width, _, _ = d.shapesize()
        yoffset = width/2 * 20 # to align the blocks by it's bottom edge
        d.sety(self.y + yoffset)
        d.setx(self.x+34*len(self))
        self.append(d)
    def _close_gap_from_i(self, i):
        for b in self[i:]:
            xpos, _ = b.pos()
            b.setx(xpos - 34)
    def _open_gap_from_i(self, i):
        for b in self[i:]:
            xpos, _ = b.pos()
            b.setx(xpos + 34)
    def pop(self, key):
        b = list.pop(self, key)
        b.glow()
        b.sety(200)
        self._close_gap_from_i(key)
        return b
    def insert(self, key, b):
        self._open_gap_from_i(key)
        list.insert(self, key, b)
        b.setx(self.x+34*key)
        width, _, _ = b.shapesize()
        yoffset = width/2 * 20 # to align the blocks by it's bottom edge
        b.sety(self.y + yoffset)
        b.unglow()

def show_text(text):
    goto(0,-250)
    write(text, align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "bold"))

def start_sort():
    onkey(None,"space")
    clear()
    show_text("sort_me")
    sort_func(s)

def init_shelf(vals=(4, 8, 2, 9, 3, 1, 10, 7, 5, 6)):
    s = Shelf(-200)
    for i in vals:
        s.push(Block(i))
    return s

def clear_window():
    getscreen().clearscreen()

def main(func):
    global sort_func
    sort_func = func
    getscreen().clearscreen()
    ht(); penup()
    init_shelf()
    show_text("press spacebar to start sorting")
    onkey(start_sort, "space")
    onkey(bye, "Escape")
    listen()
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to follow your examples of starting order and final order after calling `insert_animate()` but here's my guess at what's going wrong:

I believe you've got your `else` clause indented incorrectly (too deep) such that it has become part of the `if` statement when it really should be part of the `for` statement:

```
def insert_animate(blockposition, shelf, high):

    if blockposition == 0:
        return shelf

    a = s.pop(blockposition)

    for i in range(high):
        if a.size <= s[i].size:
            s.insert(i, a)
            break
    else:  # no break
        s.insert(high, a)

    return shelf
```

As originally written, the `else` clause could be executed multiple times but you only want it executed once, when the `for` loop exits via a means other than `break`.  An `else` clause tied to a loop in this manner can be thought of as meaning "no break", i.e. execute this code if the loop has a `break` statement but it wasn't taken.